# Run same js code on every page in website

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to create a popup that opens after 30 seconds even if the user changes  to a different page on the site.
e.g. User enters example.com and stays on the main page for 15 seconds, then navigates to a different page still on the site example.com, stays there for 15 seconds. Now I want the popup to open.

My JavaScript code to create a cookie:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        var timeElapsed;
        var targetTime = 10000;
        var myInter;

        function openPopup() {
            alert('popup');
            timeElapsed = 0;
            clearInterval(myInter);
            setCookie('alreadyDone', true, 1);
        }
        function updateCookie() {
            timeElapsed += 2000;
            setCookie('emailPopup', timeElapsed, 1);
            alert(timeElapsed);
        }
        function checkCookie() {
            if (getCookie('alreadyDone') === "") {
                if (getCookie('emailPopup') === "") {
                    timeElapsed = 0;
                    setCookie('emailPopup', timeElapsed, 1);
                } else {
                    timeElapsed = parseInt(getCookie('emailPopup'));
                    setCookie('emailPopup', timeElapsed, 1);
                }
                setTimeout(openPopup, targetTime - timeElapsed);
                myInter = setInterval(updateCookie, 2000);
            }
        }
        function getCookie(cname) {
            var name = cname + "=";
            var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
            for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
                var c = ca[i];
                while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') c = c.substring(1);
                if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
                    return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
                }
            }
            return "";
        }
        function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
            var d = new Date();
            d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
            var expires = "expires=" + d.toUTCString();
            document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires;
        } 
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="checkCookie()">
    <a href="page1.php"><button>Page 1</button></a>
</body>
```

But I need this code run on every page on my site.

Comment: Why don't you create a js file and include that on every page.

Comment: @jcubic but that exactly my problem! I can't add this line to each file. I'm using in Magento Ecommrce system, so I have a lot of files... maybe it's should be with php in server side?

Answer (score 0):

1) Create a js file called your-name.js

2) Cut this code and paste there. Save.

3) Call this file in every  of your webpages like

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/your-location/your-name.js"></script>
<head>

<body>
</body>
<html>
```

Comment: but that exactly my problem! I can't add this line to each file. I'm using in Magento Ecommrce system, so I have a lot of files... maybe it's should be with php in server side?